# R: find column with the largest column sum

Tags: r, sorting, csv

I want to find the column with the largest column sum. I am thinking of something like:

```
threeLargest = colnames(sort(colSums(data[,2:length(data)]), 
                        decreasing = TRUE)[1:3])
```

but `colnames` just gives `NULL` with the `sort(colSums...` command.

The reason is that I want to be able to refer to the values in the column and plot it. I was thinking that there had to be a more R-oriented solution than looping over the columns and keeping count of the largest ones.

I have `example_csv_file.csv`:

```
date,column1,column2,column3,column4
2013-12-09,0,0,0,2
2013-12-10,0,0,0,2
2013-12-11,0,0,0,2
2013-12-12,0,0,0,2
2013-12-13,0,0,0,2
2013-12-14,0,1,7,2
2013-12-15,2,15,36,2
2013-12-16,5,10,28,2
2013-12-17,1,2,39,2
2013-12-18,2,3,34,2
```

which I import this way:

```
data = read.csv(file = 'example_csv_file.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

I can sort the columns by their column sum, and fetch the top three:

```
threeLargest = sort(colSums(data[,2:length(data)]), decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]
```

This gives:

```
> threeLargest
column3 column2 column4 
    144      31      20
```

but I need to obtain the column names because I need to refer to the columns when I plot their values. E.g. this way:

```
plot(data[,'column3'])
```

and preferably have a list of the top ones which I could refer to in a loop, like this:

```
plot(data[,namesOfThreeLargest[1]], type = 'n')
color = 1
for (column in namesOfThreeLargest)
{
  lines(data[,column], col = color)
  color = color + 1
}
legend("topleft", inset=.05, lty = 1, namesOfThreeLargest, col = seq(color))
```

If I could obtain the number of the column in a neat way, I could get the name of it this way:

```
columnWithLargestColSum = colnames(data)[4]
```

I have tried importing the file differently, e.g. `read.table(file =...`, `read.data.frame(file =...` and `as.matrix(read.csv(file =...`, to see if `colnames` works then, but it does not. In fact `colSums` does not even work for the `as.matrix` one since the entries are strings for that method.

Thanks!

---

Edit:

This is the solution I went with:

I used `order()` from [Joris Meys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428790/joris-meys) and I used `names()` from [Ananda Mahto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270695/ananda-mahto) (see their solutions below):

```
colCount = colSums(data[-1])
topThreeIds = order(colCount,decreasing=TRUE)[1:3] + 1 # From Joris
topThreeCols = names(data[topIds]) # From Ananda
```

Note the `+ 1` in the 2nd line, due to the fact that I'm skipping the `date` column in the 1st line. By adding one in the 2nd line I get an actual id of the columns I want.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Did you try `names` instead of `colnames`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you view the `str` of the output of your `colSums` step, you'll see it's just a named vector, not anything with "columns":

```
str(sort(colSums(data[,2:length(data)]), 
                 decreasing = TRUE)[1:3])
#  Named num [1:3] 144 31 20
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "column3" "column2" "column4"
```

As such, if you want the "names", you should wrap the command in `names` instead of `colnames`.

In other words:

```
namesOfThreeLargest <- names(threeLargest)
```

From there, now that I see you just want to do multiple line plots, you can look at `matplot`, for instance:

```
matplot(data[, namesOfThreeLargest], type="l")
```

Comment: Thanks Ananda. I used `names()` together with Joris's `order()` here below.

Comment: I really like `matplot()`, as well. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

I'd not insist on using `sort()`. Using `order()` can be faster and more appropriate. You could also use the list-indexing to make your code more readible.

So

```
id <- order(colSums(Data[-1]),decreasing=TRUE)[1:3]
matplot(Data[id],type='l')
```

would be a faster and more concise way of doing it.

Comment: Good call on `order`. +1

Comment: Thanks Joris! I changed `sort()` to `order()`, and then used `names()` from Ananda.

Comment: I hadn't seen the 'skip column #a' with `data[-a]`. Thanks for that too.

Answer (score 2):

A alternative solution is to use `sort.list` instead of `sort`, which will return the columns in order from largest to smallest (add 1 to the index since we're ignoring the first column):

```
colnames(data)[sort.list(colSums(data[,-1]), decreasing=TRUE)[1:3] + 1]
```

If you're feeling particularly lazy, you can also use `rev()` to reverse the order, instead of typing out `decreasing=TRUE`:

```
colnames(data)[rev(sort.list(colSums(data[,-1])))[1:3] + 1]
```

Comment: From what I understood from the question, this would be what they are looking for: `colnames(data)[sort.list(colSums(data[,-1]), decreasing=TRUE)[1:3] + 1]`.

Comment: Ah, I missed the part where they were only looking for the top three